# ORA-29531: no method in class (java)

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I have a java procedure inside a package in Oracle:

```
procedure pREPORTTEHMOG_java(dName varchar2, dFrame number, dSlot number, dPort number) 
AS  LANGUAGE java NAME 'REPORTTEHMOG_TEST.dovuciREPORTTEHMOG_TEST(java.lang.String,int,int,int)';
```

and it is defined something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED WIS."REPORTTEHMOG_TEST" AS import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class REPORTTEHMOG_TEST {
...
public static void dovuciREPORTTEHMOG_TEST(String dName, Integer dFrame, Integer dSlot, Integer dPort) throws Exception {
 ...
}
...
}
```

When I try to call the procedure like this:

```
declare
begin
REPORT_TEHMOG.pREPORTTEHMOG_java('MA5818_Caic', 0, 1, 1);
end;
```

it throws an error:

```
ORA-29531: no method dovuciREPORTTEHMOG_TEST in class REPORTTEHMOG_TEST
```

Does anybody know the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int` primitive and [the `Integer` class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) are not the same thing, so your declaration does not match the Java method. It should be:

```
procedure pREPORTTEHMOG_java(dName varchar2, dFrame number, dSlot number, dPort number) 
AS LANGUAGE java NAME 'REPORTTEHMOG_TEST.dovuciREPORTTEHMOG_TEST(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer)';
```

Or make the Java arguments `int` if that is appropriate.